# Ionic 3 component gets called multiple times and query runs indefinetly

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5

I have a query fetching unique dates from a table and then i want to pass each date as a value to query a table and display records in html. I am using component to achieve this. But my query inside component runs indefinitely. Below is the code which i have tried.

report.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.sql.query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM walkInRecord").then((data) => {
        this.dates = data.res.rows;
      });
}
```

report.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div *ngFor="let date of dates">
      Date: {{date.date}}
      <report-table [date]="date.date"></report-table>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

report-table.ts

```
constructor(public sql: Mysql) {
    console.log("component");
  }
 ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log("Component Input: ", this.date);
    this.sql.query("SELECT * FROM walkInRecord WHERE date='" + date + "'").then((data) => {
      this.records = data.res.rows;
    });
  }
```

Component is fetching the input correctly.
I can view report after navigating 3 pages and i could see that the component's constructor is called thrice which is quite a wild behavior. Someone please let me know what could be the reason for multiple calls of a component and how to stop the query running indefinetly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes i tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

Your report-table component is rendered inside a `*ngfor` loop. Thus it will be initialized multiple times and `ngAfterContentInit` hook will be called as many times as for loop runs.

Comment: Actually, I checked it with one value in loop. When my loop had 2 value and i required 3 navigation to reach report screen, my component gets initialized (3*2) 6 times. Also my query runs indefinitely.